# Standard radix for decimal base?

Tags: numbers, decimal, radix, prefix

If I need to identify hex, octal, or binary numbers, I can just use prefixes 0x, 0, 0b.  They aren't necessarily universal but are pretty recognizable in the programming world.

Is there an identifier like that for decimal (base 10) numbers?  I would like to be able to explicitly denote a decimal base number and would like to use a somewhat standard notation if possible.

Comment: No, 8x is not "pretty recognizable".

Comment: Good point, i've edited that.  Is there any for base 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a general form, then `(number)b(base)` is used in a couple of projects. 1b10, 1b16, 1b2, etc. can give you some standard way to express bases.

I've never seen `8x` used anywhere tbh. `0` as a prefix - yes.

Answer (score 1):

The standard prefix for octal is a leading "0" (in the C / C++ / Perl worlds at least). So I wouldn't recommend using "8x".